# Black-box optimization algorithms performance

Tags: optimization, bayesian-optimization

I've been doing some basic research of the black-box optimization algorithms that are on the market (and have Python implementation). I've found some recent and promising algorithms like [LIPO](http://blog.dlib.net/2017/12/a-global-optimization-algorithm-worth.html), [SHGO](https://stefan-endres.github.io/shgo/) or [Simple(x)](https://github.com/chrisstroemel/Simple)  but I didn't manage to find any systematic and recent study that would benchmark their performance (in terms of number of function evaluations needed to find a global optimum). Both among them and compared to older algorithms.

The Bayesian optimization is another option for black-box optimization. It's widely used and sort of industry standard but I have never found any serious comparison of performance of the Bayesian optimization to the other methods like those above (that would be the best) or more classical like [Pattern search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_search_(optimization)), [CMA-ES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMA-ES) or other evolutionary and genetic algorithms.

So my question is if there is some comparison of the Bayesian optimization against the other methods (recent ones (LIPO, SHGO) or "classical")? If there's nothing like that (I guess I would have found that) can you compare among these algorithms?

There is nice [paper](http://thales.cheme.cmu.edu/dfo/comparison/dfo.pdf) by Rios and Sahinidis that systematically compares algorithms/implementations but it's relatively old (so that LIPO and SHGO couldn't be included) and it completely avoids Bayesian optimization as well.

Comment: The LIPO paper includes some benchmarks against BayesOpt. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02628.pdf Is that responsive, or are you asking for a different kind of comparison?

Comment: I would like to see something a bit more systematic and also independent (of the algorithm authors). Simply something similar to Rios Sahinidis paper. But also personal real usage experience would be valuable.

Comment: BO is an industry-standard because it mostly deals with computationally expensive applications. There are a plethora of factors one needs to consider before such a benchmark study is conducted (and a plethora is an understatement). Just to give you an idea: dimensionality, hardware, software (implementation and languages), time for functional evaluations. These factors need to be accounted for somehow. Different Gaussian process implementations also perform differently (and I have not accounted for the internal hyper-parameters within GP -- such as how well a GP should be fitted)..

Comment: BO has even more hyper-parameters than GP. And for each runs, you need to repeat 10-50-100 times to get statistically stable results. The amount of works is simply insane. And if you are serious about benchmarking, then you should compare across hardware as well, e.g. are Intel chips better than AMD? That's probably why we have something called the No Free Lunch Theorem.

Comment: You can search "Optimizer Elo Ratings". A more comprehensive answer to you question was deleted by moderators.